# How to use a TestProbe as a child actor in akka tests?

Tags: akka, akka-actor

When testing some parent actor, it would be convenient if any child actors it created were `TestProbe`s. This can be achieved as suggested in the docs, by:

> Externalize child making from the parent

However, this does not work for tests that involve stopping child actors, because only the direct parent of an actor is allowed to stop it.

Is there any other technique that will work here?

Comment: How do you stopping child actors? Could you provide some code example?

Answer (score 0):

First, isolate the creation of the child to a method inside the actor you want to test.

Then, for testing, subclass the actor under test and override that method to return a TestProbe.